# 'Disabled' constraints preventing MERGE OUTPUT from working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
CREATE TABLE a(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    val INT
);

CREATE TABLE b(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    val INT
);

CREATE TABLE a_b(
    fk_a INT,
    fk_b INT
);

CREATE TABLE c(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    a_val INT,
    b_val INT
);

ALTER TABLE a_b ADD CONSTRAINT fk_a_b_fk_a FOREIGN KEY (fk_a) REFERENCES a(id);
ALTER TABLE a_b ADD CONSTRAINT fk_a_b_fk_b FOREIGN KEY (fk_b) REFERENCES b(id);

INSERT INTO a(val) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO b(val) VALUES (2), (4), (6);


ALTER TABLE a_b NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        a.id AS 'a_id',
        a.val AS 'a_val',
        b.id AS 'b_id',
        b.val AS 'b_val'
    FROM a
        INNER JOIN b
            ON a.id = b.id
)
MERGE INTO c
    USING cte ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (a_val, b_val)
    VALUES (cte.a_val, cte.b_val)
OUTPUT cte.a_id, cte.b_id INTO a_b(fk_a, fk_b);

ALTER TABLE a_b WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;

SELECT * FROM c;
```

The error I'm getting is:

> The target table 'a_b' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be on either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship. Found reference constraint 'fk_a_b_fk_a'.

However, I'm very clearly disabling the constraints surrounding the merge statement. Is there any way to fix this?

The same thing goes for/is happening with triggers and disabling them surrounding the merge statement doesn't work.

Comment: I just checked on SQL Server 2014 and the `alter table a_b nocheck constraint all` works as expected.  When the constraints are in place, I get your error.  When the constraints are suspended, the data is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CREATE  TABLE #a(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    val INT
);

CREATE TABLE #b(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    val INT
);

CREATE TABLE #a_b(
    fk_a INT,
    fk_b INT
);

CREATE TABLE #c(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    a_val INT,
    b_val INT
);

ALTER TABLE #a_b ADD CONSTRAINT fk_a_b_fk_a FOREIGN KEY (fk_a) REFERENCES a(id);
ALTER TABLE #a_b ADD CONSTRAINT fk_a_b_fk_b FOREIGN KEY (fk_b) REFERENCES b(id);

INSERT INTO #a(val) VALUES (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO #b(val) VALUES (2), (4), (6);


WITH cte AS (

 SELECT
        a.id AS 'a_id',
        a.val AS 'a_val',
        b.id AS 'b_id',
        b.val AS 'b_val'
    FROM #a a
        INNER JOIN #b b
            ON a.id = b.id
)
MERGE INTO #c
    USING cte ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (a_val, b_val)
    VALUES (cte.a_val, cte.b_val)
OUTPUT cte.a_id, cte.b_id INTO #a_b(fk_a, fk_b);

SELECT * FROM #c;
```

Comment: I'm not trying to use/create temporary tables, I'm just sharing an minimal example that recreates the problem.

Comment: actually i tried with the temp tables but i achieved the result without any errors as mentioned above.